# Qt QML How to find the width and height of a Shape?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm using a `Shape` drawn using a `ShapePath` with a `PathSvg`, like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12
import QtQml 2.12

Item
{
    property var m
    property color col: "white"

    Shape
    {
        id: ashape
        containsMode: Shape.FillContains

        ShapePath 
        {
            strokeWidth: 1
            strokeColor: "transparent"
            fillColor: col

            PathSvg
            {
                path: m.path
            }
        }
    }

    Text
    {
       width: ashape.implicitWidth   // these are zero
       height: ashape.implicitHeight  // so it doesnt work

        color: "white"
        text: "hello"
        font.pointSize: 12
    }
}
```

I wanted to place some `Text` over the shape, but i can't get the width and height for the placement of the text.

Any ideas?
thanks.

### Update

Here is a a complete example. I want the text to appear over the shape;

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Shapes 1.12
import QtQml 2.12


ApplicationWindow
{
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Shape
    {
        id: ashape        
        ShapePath 
        {

            fillColor: "red"

            PathSvg
            {
                path: "M100 100 l0 100 l100 0 Z"
            }
        }

        Text
        {
            // want the text to appear over the shape
            text: "hello"
            font.pointSize: 12
        }
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

q.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app

QT += qml quick quickcontrols2
CONFIG += console

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc
```

### Update 2

Picture of above;

[image]

Comment: As I see `Shape` derived from `Item` and so has such properties like `width()` and `height()`. But the right and _declarative_ way in this case I think is to use anchors, i.e. you have to place `Text` inside `Shape` and set `anchors.centerIn: parent`. QtQuick will do all the work for you.

Comment: @folibis Nice try, but it didnt work. `Shape` has no size, putting `anchors.fil: parent` in Shape doesnt work because `Item` has no size. `Item` has no size because i dont know the size of `ShapePath` which also has no size. It draws the shape but there is no size to anchor to or otherwise.

Comment: Could you please provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can run and test it? i.e. `m.path` etc ...

Comment: @folibis Thanks. I added more example. If you put in your `centerIn: parent` idea, the "hello" text moves off the top left corner, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, it looks like you have to explicitly set the size of the `Shape`